# Creating a radar chart with d3 and multiple diagonal brushes

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, brush

I am looking to create a radar chart with multiple diagonal brush selections. I have the radar chart [here](http://jsbin.com/AyAFIHI/12/), and there are examples of using multiple brushes with [parcoords](http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/). However, I have not seen any examples of using a brush to select on the diagnoal. Basically, I would like to turn this parallel coordinate chart into a radar chart, keeping the brushing capabilities, but I am not sure how to do this, as the axes will be at random places and angles. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change axis generation in parcoords. It's hard-coded as a set of parallel vertical lines.

You would have to modify parcoords.js to suit your needs, which does not seem to be a trivial task.